# Counting roots by Rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve this question from a complex analysis book by Davis Ullrich:
I am trying to show that the polynomial $F(z) = z^n(z-2)-1$ has exactly $n$ roots in the open disk centered at $0$ of radius $1$.
I am trying to use another polynomial $G(z)$ with $n$ roots and have $F$ and $G$ satisfy $|F-G|<|F|+|G|$. I am not convinced that $F$ has $n$ roots and so I am not sure about my choice of $G$ for which I assert that it has $n$ roots. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On the unit circle $|z|=1$ therefore by the triangle inequality $|z-2|\geq 1$ and hence $|z^n(z-2)|\geq 1$. This shows that on the unit circle, we have $F(z)\not=0$ unless equalities hold in all inequalities above. But that would imply that $z=1$ where $F(z)$ takes the value $(1)^n(1-2)-1\not=2$. Thus in all cases the polynomial does not vanish on the unit circle. Now consider the deformation $z^n(z-2)-t$ as $t$ decreases from $1$ to $0$. By a similar argument all intermediate polynomials don't vanish on the unit circle. Therefore $F$ has the same number of zeros inside the circle as $z^n(z-2)$.